# NiFi HandleHttpResponse 503 Errors

Tags: http, jetty, apache-nifi

In NiFi, I have an HTTP endpoint that accepts POST requests with payloads varying from 7kb to 387kb or larger (up to 4mb). The goal is to have a clustered implementation capable of handling approximately 10,000 requests per second. However, no matter if I have NiFi clustered with 3 nodes or a single instance, I've never been able to average more than 15-20 requests/second without the Jetty service returning a 503 error. I've tried reducing the time penalty and increasing the number of Maximum Outstanding Requests in the StandardHttpContextMap. No matter what I try, whether on my local machine or on a remote VM, I cannot get any impressive number of requests to go through.

Any idea why this is occurring and how to fix this? Even when clustering, I notice one node (not even the primary node) does the majority of the work and I think this explains why the throughput isn't much higher for a clustered implementation.

No matter at what bulletin level, this is the error I get in the nifi-app.log:

```
2016-08-09 09:54:41,568 INFO [qtp1644282758-117] o.a.n.p.standard.HandleHttpRequest HandleHttpRequest[id=6e30cb0d-221f-4b36-b35f-735484e05bf0] Sending back a SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE response to 127.0.0.1; request was POST 127.0.0.1
```

This is the same whether I'm running just two processors (HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse) as my only processors or I have my general flow where I'm routing on content, replacing some text, and writing to a database or jms messaging system. I can get higher throughput (up to 40 requests/sec) when I'm running just the web service without my entire flow, but it still has a KO rate of about 90%, so it's not much better - still seems to be an issue with the jetty service.

Comment: What is your ThreadPool configuration on the Jetty side?

Comment: The default value, nifi.web.jetty.threads=200 in nifi.properties

Comment: Hello.  Can you please share details on the 503 response you're seeing.  That means there should be something in nifi/logs/nifi-app.log.  You should be able to achieve far higher numbers for sure.  Also whether it is clustered or not should not matter.  The clients pushing to the cluster will need to distribute the workload or you'll need an HTTP load balancer in front.

Comment: Can you share some more detail on your flow?  What happens between HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResonse?

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: FWIW the Jetty Server is created by doing Server server = new Server(port); which as far as I can tell uses a QueuedThreadPool behind the scenes with a max of 200 threads and min of 8, so I would think there are enough threads available.

Comment: How do memory, disk IO, and file descriptor resources look?

Comment: Memory and Disk usage will spike definitely, but they're nowhere near maxed out. And I'm seeing similar throughput failures on both my local laptop with modest hardware, and our cloud-based VM with a lot of compute resources.